# Modify JS to allow more than 1 modal on a page

Tags: javascript, simplemodal

I'm  using a modal to display a image-slider for different references of my website.
This is how my references look like:

```
<div>
    <a id="openmodal">
       <p>Project 1</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a id="openmodal">
        <p>Project 2</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a id="openmodal">
        <p>Project 3</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the structure of my modal(s)

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Title</p>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
      <img src="image1.jpg">
      <img src="image2.jpg">
      <img src="image3.jpg">
      <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlider(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="next" onclick="plusSlider(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="modal2" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Title</p>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
      <img src="image1.jpg">
      <img src="image2.jpg">
      <img src="image3.jpg">
      <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlider(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="next" onclick="plusSlider(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div> 


<div id="modal3" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Title</p>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
      <img src="image1.jpg">
      <img src="image2.jpg">
      <img src="image3.jpg">
      <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlider(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="next" onclick="plusSlider(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS looks like this:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal1");

var btn = document.getElementById("openmodal");

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Unfortunately don't know how to modify the JS if i want use more than one modal (with the id="modal2" and id="modal3" ...) on a html page. Or how can i use each modal for each project? Maybe someone can help me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is `plusSlider` function?

Comment: Has something to do with the image-slider IN the modal.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are using the same id on all the anchor tags which is wrong. You should only have one id per page. You can instead add a common class and add event listeners on them.

Here in the below code we have added class `openmodal` for all the anchor links and added `data-id` attribute to differentiate them. On button click we just get this id and open the modal dynamically. This way it will work even if you plan to add more modals to the page.

You can try out something like below.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".openmodal");
btns.forEach(btn => {
    const id = btn.getAttribute('data-id');
    btn.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  }
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.closest('.modal') && !event.target.closest('.openmodal')) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(modal => {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="openmodal"  data-id="modal1">
        <p>Project 1</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="openmodal" data-id="modal2">
        <p>Project 2</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="openmodal"  data-id="modal3">
        <p>Project 3</p>
    </a>
</div>


<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  Modal 1
</div>

<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  Modal 2
</div> 

<div id="modal3" class="modal">
  Modal 3
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, tried it and it works almost perfect.
What about this:

Comment: // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
 if (event.target == modal) {
   modal.style.display = "none";
 }
}

Comment: That seems to be prevented now

Comment: Oh, and also: if i click on my element to open the modal with the slider: i can click through my 3 images but then there are also 3 empty frames, before the acutal images are shown again.

Comment: @VRground Updated for outside click.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! But the outside click does not work. :( I am so sorry for taking so much of your time and knowledge

Comment: Working for me in this snippet. Try clicking on empty space below the modal when it is shown.

Comment: Yes, i see. I'm afraid some of my other scripts causes it to stop working in my frontend. I'm already looking for solutions.

Do you have any idea what might cause the 3 empty frames in my slider?

Comment: So ... if i have 5 images in my slider there are 5 empty frames.
Would you mind having a look over my slider script?

Comment: No idea about the slider. You might want to check the slider doc that you are using. Must be the slider initialisation is conflicting with other slider initialisation. Just a guess.